# wso2 mediator dynamic url

Tags: http, wso2, esb, mediator, wso2-esb

I have some problems in the next situation:
I have wso2esb and a there is proxy-service in the esb.
I call this proxy with parameters with parameter, e.g. 
`http://host:9643/service/myproxy?domain=first.`
After that my proxy need to get to the next endpoint: `http://first.mysite.com` 
if we have `http://host:9643/service/myproxy?domain=second` we will have to get to the `http://second.mysite.com`

Answer (score 0):

You get your parameter inside the proxy service using.

```
<property name="domain" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2"/>
```

And then you need to use switch mediator inside proxy service's insequence and then based on the case you need use send mediator to send the message to required endpoing.

This will be helpful to understand the scenario.
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IntegrationPatterns/Dynamic+Router

Comment: thank you! So, we have situation where we do not know about parameter domain, it is dynamic. It is generated into java code. In the proxy service we have to get it from request and put (paste) to the endpoitn.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: For that you can use header mediator to set "To" Address header and then send to "default" endpoint and message will be routed to the defined address in "To" Header. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Header+Mediator